# Xcode 4 gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, gcc

Any idea why my build is failing on the following process? I have 2 other targets in this project that build just fine. I cannot see any clear reason based on this what the issue is. I've compared all the build settings in each target and all seems to be well/the same.

Any help is appreciated.

```
ProcessPCH /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gphlhvxbcddmbydldqumpamkmmwu/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/MyApp_Prefix-bknmhqekgexlchfcpbduwcqlcafa/MyApp_Prefix.pch.gch MyApp_Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
    cd /Users/me/Development/myapp/trunk
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c-header -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -DDEBUG_LOGS_ON -DMyApp -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -mthumb -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -iquote "/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gphlhvxbcddmbydldqumpamkmmwu/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/MyApp-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gphlhvxbcddmbydldqumpamkmmwu/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/MyApp-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gphlhvxbcddmbydldqumpamkmmwu/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/MyApp-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gphlhvxbcddmbydldqumpamkmmwu/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/MyApp-project-headers.hmap" -I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gphlhvxbcddmbydldqumpamkmmwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gphlhvxbcddmbydldqumpamkmmwu/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gphlhvxbcddmbydldqumpamkmmwu/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gphlhvxbcddmbydldqumpamkmmwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -c /Users/me/Development/myapp/trunk/MyApp_Prefix.pch -o /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gphlhvxbcddmbydldqumpamkmmwu/Build/PrecompiledHeaders/MyApp_Prefix-bknmhqekgexlchfcpbduwcqlcafa/MyApp_Prefix.pch.gch

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. I had a preprocessor macro for this target that started with a number e.g. "123TEST", evidently the compiler does not like numbers first, "TEST123" works fine.

Comment: U saved my day :-) Those errors are written in a Marsian lng.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at MyApp_Prefix.pch. The compiler doesn't like it.

Comment: The same pch file is used for the other 2 targets that compile fine.